# How to import standalone components from a lib in Angular 14?

Tags: angular, angular14

Angular 14 introduced new *standalone* components, which doesn't require any module to be used. How can such components be used if provided in a library? In standard, non-standalone components, we first had to import a given module. How Angular will recognize that component I'm importing comes from this particular package?

Comment: Is this going to work this way that I have to import such a standalone component to a module I want to use it in?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To make a standalone component, you need to define the component as [`standalone`](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#standalone) using the `standalone` parameter in the decorator of the component, then you can use the [`imports`](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#imports) statement in the component as well.

To generate using the standalone flag:

```bash
ng generate component example-component --standalone
```

If instead, if you would like your whole project to be standalone, you can add the [`standalone`](https://angular.io/cli/new#options) flag to the `new` command, and then you don't have to specify `standalone` on the `generate` command:

```bash
ng new my-application --standalone

ng g c example-component
```

Your component would then look like this:

```js
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  selector: 'example-component',
  template: `./example.component.html`,
})
export class ExampleComponent {}
```

Next you need to import the component into other components/modules. You now can import it into your module in the `import` property which wasn't supported before. Or you can import it into another component which also wasn't supported at all, and now is.

**Note:** Components importing a component also need the `standalone` property.

```js
// Importing using a Module
@NgModule({
  imports: [ExampleComponent]
})
export class MyModule {}

// Importing using a component
// This component also needs the standalone property
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ExampleComponent],
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `./component.html`,
})
export class OtherExampleComponent {}
```

Comment: I forget to that the importing component also need the standalone property

Comment: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0201: No provider for NgControl found in NodeInjector. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0201` I get this error when trying to add it in the decorator for `@Component`  and the `imports` property.

Comment: AFAIK, it is **not** required that the importing Module/Component is also standalone: see [ng14 docs](https://v14.angular.io/guide/standalone-components#using-standalone-components-in-ngmodule-based-applications)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use a standalone component in another component A, you need to import the standalone component  in component A like below,

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [StandaloneComponent],
  selector: 'demo-component',
  template: `./demo.component.html`,
})
```